# Regex substitution in Python to add period to sentence that doesn't have one but only if it is the only line in string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to add periods to a single sentence in a string that doesn't have one, such as

```
string = "This is a sentence"
```

But while avoiding adding periods to things like

```
string = "Item 1\nItem 2\nItem 3"
```

So is there a way to add periods to a sentence if it is the only line in a string? Thanks.

Comment: why couldn't you just do `if not '\n' in s: s+='.'
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can do it without regex. Take a look if these conditions are enough in your case:

```
s = "Some string"
s += "." if s[0].isupper() and not s.endswith(".") and "\n" not in s else ""
```

Comment: I was looking into regex because I already had a bunch of other regular expression rules for other grammatical fixes, but I suppose this is just as brief. Thanks.